# How to move all files in a subfolder except certain files

Tags: bash, grep, find, xargs

I usually download with filezilla in the directory `/Public/Downloads` on my nas.

I made a script executed by filezilla when download queue is finished, so all my downloads are moved to `/Public/Downloads/Completed`. My directory `/Public/Downloads` contains also two files and three directories that must not be moved.

```
folder.jpg
log.txt
Temp
Cache
Completed
```

I tried this command:

```
find /Public/Downloads/* -maxdepth 1 | grep -v Completed | grep -v Cache | grep -v Temp | grep -v log.txt | grep -v folder.jpg | xargs -i mv {} /Public/Downloads/Completed
```

This works for downloaded files and folders named without special characters: they are moved to `/Public/Downloads/Completed`
But when there is a <space> or an `à` or something else special, xarg is complaining *unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option*

I've searched a solution by myself but haven't find something for my needs combining find, grep and xargs for files and directories.

How do I have to modify my command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a suggestion for your ***change strategy*** and not about `xargs`. You only need the `bash` shell and `mv` for the external tool.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob extglob

array=( 
  folder.jpg
  log.txt
  Temp
  Cache 
  Completed
)

to_skip=$(IFS='|'; printf '%s' "*@(${array[*]})")

for item in /Public/Downloads/*; do
  [[ $item == $to_skip ]] && continue
  echo mv -v "$item" /Public/Downloads/Completed/ || exit
done
```

- Remove the `echo` if you think that the output is correct.
- Add the `-x` e.g. `set -x` (after the shebang) option to see which/what the code is doing or `bash -x my_script`, assuming `my_script` is the name of your script.

Answer (score 0):

So i've changed my strategy for a loop using a temporary text file:

```
#!/bin/bash

ls -p /Public/Downloads | grep -v "Cache/" | grep -v "Temp/" | grep -v "Completed/" | grep -v 'log.txt' | grep -v 'folder.jpg' >/Public/Downloads/Completed/temp.txt
cat /Public/Downloads/Completed/temp.txt |\
    while IFS='' read -r CURRENT || [ -n "$CURRENT" ]; do
    mv /Public/Downloads/"$CURRENT" /Public/Downloads/Completed
    done
rm /Public/Downloads/Completed/temp.txt
```

1) I write a list of directories and files to be moved with "ls" in "temp.txt"

2) Each line of "temp.txt" is passed into the $CURRENT variable. So each file and directory is moved one by one with "mv". The variable $CURRENT is double quoted in the mv command in case of "space" character in the name of the directory or the file

3) "temp.txt" is deleted

Answer (score 0):

Based on OP input, the main issue is files name with "special" characters, including space. Two options:

- If none of the input files has embedded new line in the file name (which is the case), the problem can be addressed by explicit specification of the delimited string to new line (-d '\n'). See below
- If any of the files can contain new line in the name, the whole pipeline has to use zero-terminated strings. Does not seems to be the case here.

```
find /Public/Downloads/* -maxdepth 1 |
    grep -v Completed |
    grep -v Cache |
    grep -v Temp |
    grep -v log.txt |
    grep -v folder.jpg |
    xargs -d '\n' -i mv {} /Public/Downloads/Completed
```